# CRA + React Leaflet: failed to compile

Tags: create-react-app, react-leaflet

I've just started a brand new project using `create-react-app` and set up `react-leaflet` as their documentation recommends [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-installation).

I am trying to use [this example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup) to check if it's all working good but then I'm receiving the following error:

```
./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

Looks like `react-scripts` can't handle `react-leaflet` files.
Can someone helps me to understand why it's happening and how do I fix it ?

Comment: There is already a discussion of this going on over here: [How to fix error “Failed to compile : ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node\_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Answer (score 16):

**After reading about it on all blogs , I have concluded that :**
It's because of the new version of the react-leaflet. I faced the same problem and here's how I got rid of the error:

Open your **package.json** file

```
 "browserslist": {
 "production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
},
```

Replace it with following lines :

```
"browserslist": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
```

- Now Delete node_modeules/.cache folder
- **npm install**
- **npm start**

Another method is to just add these lines in your package.json file:

```
"react-leaflet": ">=3.1.0 <3.2.0 || ^3.2.1",
"@react-leaflet/core": ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0 || ^1.1.1"
```

- This will **skip** the newly released version of the *[@react-leaflet/core package](https://react-leaflet.js.org/)*

Comment: The second method worked for me (didn't try the first one).
Make sure to erase your cache folder as stated, but I would say also package-lock.json

Comment: Here is a video that has the same fix if you’re a visual learner. https://youtu.be/tFqj-JKYr4M

Comment: The video is what I needed, thanks @Adam

Comment: Happy it helped.

Comment: thanks, the video helped me too!