# How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to create a **react-typescript** app along with **leaflet**. I used the command,

`npm install leaflet react-leaflet @types/react @types/leaflet --save` to install the dependencies.

But when I start the application it says,

```
    ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "aq-monitor",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.13",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.5",
    "antd": "^4.15.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

Here's map/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import L, { LatLngExpression } from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import {MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup} from 'react-leaflet';

const position : LatLngExpression = [59.91174337077401, 10.750425582038146];

export default function MapJar() {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={position}>
                <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
    );
};
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies several times but still didn't work.

I understand this is a simple issue and an error that I am making but however, I have not been able to resolve this error.

Comment: This seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468) with CRA.  On the other hand, the @react-leaflet/core module has a tsconfig target of ES2019, which means that `??` operator should have been transpiled to something else when the package was built.  I would consider opening an issue on the react-leaflet repo saying that this line doesn't seem to be properly compiling to ES2019 as the tsconfig specifies

Comment: Thank you @SethLutske! I found the exact issue posted few hours ago https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877

Answer (score 114, accepted):

**I found a way to fix it.**

Steps to fix:

1. Open your *package.json* file and edit your browserslist as follows.

<sup>Following configuration is quoted from *[?? Operator results in "Unexpected Token" err when used in package #9468](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642)*, originally suggested by [bkiac](https://github.com/bkiac)</sup>

> ```
>  "browserslist": {
>    "production": [
>       ">0.2%",
>       "not dead",
>       "not op_mini all"
>     ],
>     "development": [
>       "last 1 chrome version",
>       "last 1 firefox version",
>       "last 1 safari version"
>     ]
> },
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> "browserslist": [
>    ">0.2%",
>   "not dead",
>   "not op_mini all"
> ],
> ```

2. Once you've done this, delete the `node_modules/.cache` directory.
3. Then try `npm install`.
4. And `npm start`

**Tadaaa!**

References:

- *[?? Operator results in "Unexpected Token" err when used in package #9468](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642)*
- *[Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41) in @react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js #877](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877)*

Comment: did you try deleting the node_modules/.cache directory? @hoogw

Comment: I tried this, but then on `npm start`, I get the prompt: "We're unable to detect target browsers.  Would you like to add the defaults to your package.json? › (Y/n)". If I hit no, CRA exits with the message "As of react-scripts >=2 you must specify targeted browsers. Please add a browserslist key to your package.json."  If I hit yes, it overwrites my package.json back to how it was, continues, and then fails again with the same message.  This is with react-scripts 4.0.1.  Has anyone encountered that?  Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! rm -rf node_modules/.cache/ was **necessary**.

Comment: My package.json already looked like how you point out it looks like. My error, the same as OP's persists... and I've tried to remove the cache folder and delete node_modules entirely. It's still not working.

Comment: For browsers, I simply set browserslist to `[ "defaults" ]`. Unless you have a reason to more restrictive settings, that will do.

Comment: Just remove development content `"development": []`

Comment: The configuration is the exact same as [kboul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat/67566183#67566183) (both copied from the GitHub page(?)). Just listing references may not be sufficient attribution for a straight copy-paste. What is the corresponding meta question?

Comment: From *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-entirely-copied-and-improperly-attributed-o/321326#321326)* (despite the title, it seems to cover this situation): *"The blockquote markup is used to indicate, typographically, the portions of the content that come from that source, and therefore not original content."* and *"Provide the name of the original author"*

Comment: Worked thanks!

@SethLutske important to know that `browserList` changes from an object to an array

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly the solution that fixes it!

Answer (score 31):

The issue eventually seems to be related with create-react-app and the way it bundles files and seems to be resolved if you replace browser targets from:

```
"browserslist": {
   "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
},
```

to

```
"browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
```

Then stop the server and rerun it.

Credits go to **bkiac** [official create-react-app GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642)

You can reproduce the error and the fix if you download [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-how-to-fix-the-error-you-may-need-an-additional-loader-dygxz?file=/package.json). When you open it, it works, but if you download it and run it locally, you can see the error using the first `browserslist` options in `package.json`. If you stop the server, replace `browserslist` options with the new and rerun the application you can see that it works as expected.

Comment: In my case, if you remove the development object, react answers with the following: "As of react-scripts >=2 you must specify targeted browsers.". Then it exits. Which version of react-scripts do you have?

Comment: `"react-leaflet": "^3.2.0"` and `"react-scripts": "4.0.3"`

Comment: As suggested below you should also remove cache: node_modules/.cache. This worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

I encountered this problem after I did an npm update.

These packages were installed:
`"react-leaflet": "^3.2.0"`

and as dependency (found in .lock):
`"@react-leaflet/core": "1.1.0",`

Forcing npm to use these versions, fixed it for me:

`"@react-leaflet/core": "1.0.2",`

`"react-leaflet": "3.1.0",`

So try `npm i react-leaflet@3.1.0 @react-leaflet/core@1.0.2`

Comment: Thanks @SchitzelKraft! This is the solution that worked for me after many other attempts. One I thought promising was https://stackoverflow.com/a/67991412/558732 but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed the issue by changing the `browserslist` as others have stated. My `browserslist` now looks like this:

```
"browserslist": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
]
```

I then did the following:

1. Delete your [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder
2. Run `npm cache clean --force`
3. Run `npm install`

Now everything should work as expected. If the map is not loaded, don't forget to add the leaflet CSS and JavaScript to your page and set the height for your map-container. See the [official documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

Hacking your `browserslist` or downgrading packages is not a secure or long-term solution to dealing with modules that [don't target a reasonable version of JS](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877#issuecomment-853256909). [jlahd's answer](https://jlahd) is great, except that `react-app-rewire-babel-loader` is [no longer supported](https://github.com/dashed/react-app-rewire-babel-loader#user-content--not-maintained-for-react-app-rewired-v2xx) by its author. You can achieve the same result even more easily with [`customize-cra`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) (which you should be using with CRA anyway, since that's the only way to configure your [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)) by using [`babelInclude`](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#babelinclude):

```
// config-overrides.js

const { babelInclude, override } = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
    babelInclude([
      path.resolve('src'),
      path.resolve('node_modules/@react-leaflet'),
      path.resolve('node_modules/react-leaflet')
    ])
    // and configure other stuff here like csp-html-webpack-plugin
  ),
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your reasoning and approach to solving this problem -- quick fixes that muck with settings instead of solving an underlying issue are not the way forward. I am about to try this solution and I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: I am still running into the same exact issue: "Failed to compile", and points me to `./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)`

Comment: One difference from the OP is that my file is being processed by a different loader (and this is beyond my understanding at this point): `File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.`

Comment: Are your npm scripts using `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts`? I'm using exactly the file above in one of my internal projects (so no CSP stuff needed).

Comment: I didn't change them manually no. Would installing customize-cra and react-app-rewired have changed them? I ended up going with @SchitzelKraft's solution (above, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689949/558732) and after removing node-modules and cleaning cache, the version changes worked. I should like to test your solution and making sure the react-scripts are replaced.

Comment: You need to manually change them to `react-app-rewired`: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#3-flip-the-existing-calls-to-react-scripts-in-npm-scripts-for-start-build-and-test

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but all the solutions planned here did not convince me. So I solved it in the following way:

```bash
yarn add -D @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator
```

Then I added it to the Babel plugins in `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    // ... some presets here
  ],
  plugins: [
    // ... any plugins here
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
  ],
  env: {
    // ... your configuration
  },
}
```

As the problem arises, because the library is using the nullish (??) operator, I should add it to the list of exclusions of the bable-loader in [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack).

```js
// webpack.common.js

module.exports = {
   // ... some configuration here
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        // the @react-leaflet and react-leaflet libraries must be excluded.
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(@react-leaflet|react-leaflet)\/)/i,
        use: []
      }
    ],
   // ... more configuration here

}
```

Comment: Not sure how to apply this to Storybook for instance, though it seems the most reasonable solution

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
"react-leaflet": ">=3.1.0 <3.2.0 || ^3.2.1",
"@react-leaflet/core": ">=1.0.0 <1.1.0 || ^1.1.1"
```

in "package.json"

[GitHub](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/879#issuecomment-842239921)

#### The second solution

If you still have problems, it may be from the *package.json* file. Check that it is like the following file:

```
 {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "antd": "^4.15.6",
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "leaflet.marker.slideto": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-leaflet": "3.0.2",
    "react-leaflet-drift-marker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly apply to the original question (the instructions are for *[create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)* (CRA) originated projects), but I'm still writing the answer in case some CRA user besides myself happens to stumble on this question.

- I did not want to force the use of an older *react-leaflet* version
- The browser list changes suggested in a couple of answers did not work as I am using *create-react-app* (`yarn start` just forced a refresh of the configuration)
- [WITO's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat/67747605#67747605) did not work directly, due to the same reason (due to use of *create-react-app* there isn't any direct control of the Webpack/Babel configuration files)
- Ejecting from CRA would have been an option, but I preferred not to go that way for this reason alone.

What finally did work was using the two libraries [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) and [react-app-rewire-babel-loader](https://github.com/dashed/react-app-rewire-babel-loader). Steps necessary:

1. `yarn add -D react-app-rewired react-app-rewire-babel-loader`
2. Change script names in `package.json` according to the instructions for react-app-rewired:

   ```json
     /* package.json */

     "scripts": {
   -   "start": "react-scripts start",
   +   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   -   "build": "react-scripts build",
   +   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   -   "test": "react-scripts test",
   +   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   }
   ```
3. Create `config-overrides.js` in the project's root according to instructions for react-app-rewire-babel-loader:

   ```
   /* config-overrides.js */

   const path = require("path");
   const fs = require("fs");
   const rewireBabelLoader = require("react-app-rewire-babel-loader");

   const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
   const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

   module.exports = function override(config, env) {
       config = rewireBabelLoader.include(
           config,
           resolveApp("node_modules/@react-leaflet")
       );
       config = rewireBabelLoader.include(
           config,
           resolveApp("node_modules/react-leaflet")
       );

       return config;
   };
   ```

And then it works. Basically, this includes *react-leaflet* in [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) transpiling in the same way [WITO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat/67747605#67747605) does for non-CRA builds.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, though `react-app-rewire-babel-loader` is [no longer supported](https://github.com/dashed/react-app-rewire-babel-loader#user-content--not-maintained-for-react-app-rewired-v2xx).

Answer (score 2):

After installing *react-leaflet*, the existing package.json will be like this:

```
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
```

But on running this, it will show an error like this:

```
 ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
>       const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;
```

1. To fix the bug, change the above *package.json* file to (as an
   array):

> ```
> "browserslist": [
>     ">0.2%",
>     "not dead",
>     "not op_mini all"
>   ],
> ```

2. After that, go to [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) and delete the **.cache** folder
3. Stop the server using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
4. Do **npm install** again

Answer (score 1):

For those running [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

You can fix this enabling [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) 5 in *next.config.js* file.

```js
const nextConfig = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Thanks to this comment from marcin-piechaczek:
*[Nullish coalescing operator makes package incompatible with webpack 4 #883](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/883#issuecomment-849126348)*

I got this error after upgrade react-leaflet to version 3.2.0 to fix an error while removing markers with permanent tooltips from the map.

Comment: Quick fix and it did the job for a nextjs project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In its source code, React-Leaflet (RL) uses the [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) which is not  supported by a specific version of Acorn.

For more details, check nnatter's explanation here:

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/883

**To fix the problem, you can:**

1. use nnater's suggested solution:

   https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator

   or
2. instead of using the official React-Leaflet package, you can use

   ```
    npm install --save @monsonjeremy/react-leaflet
   ```

   From

   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monsonjeremy/react-leaflet

   which is a fork of RL 3.2.1.

That way you do not have to downgrade nor do funny stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using version 3.2.0 of react-leaflet. The solution in a previous answer worked, but I want to add a couple of details for clarification purpose:

```
"browserslist":
[
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
```

***Note that***: The above *package.json* code need to be exact, meaning there aren't any `{ }` in the above code after you have deleted:

```
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
```

from:

```
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]},
```

Separately, on your terminal, type `cd` followed by `ls` to see if there are any *package.json* files and *node_modules* lying around. If they are there, `rm -rf filename` to delete them (as you may have added them by mistake over time when you forgot to navigate to your project and `npm i or yarn` them by mistake).

Finally, install *react-leaflet* again and it should work. (Note: see if your *package.json* has been updated to 3.2.0 (or the latest version) after you have reinstalled to the latest version. If not, just change the react-leaflet on your *package.json* file to the latest installed version manually.)

Answer (score 0):

Add "@types/leaflet": "1.7.0" into dependencies of package.json.

Answer (score 0):

**For those who use [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)**

Create a map in a component and import with `ssr:false;`

Example:

Component: Map.js

```
const OpenMap = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <MapContainer MapContainer style={{ height: '300px' }} center={[60.198334, 24.934541]} zoom={10}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Import the map into a page or where you need it like this:

#### File *Somewhere.js*

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'; // for dynamic importing
const OpenMap = dynamic(() => import('@/features/client/location/components/OpenMap'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Then you can use it...

Also, you can add a loading component if needed.

For more details of dynamic import check the link by clicking [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update *react-scripts* to solve this problem in file *package.json*:

```
"react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these modules in file *package.json*:

```
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^3.2.0",
```

Then remove the *@react-leaflet* folder in the [node_modules folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) in your system with cmd in any folder.

```
git clone https://github.com/hqdung99/maps-leaflet-youtube.git
```

When finished, go to the folder node_modules and copy this folder @react-leaflet and past into the *previous* node_modules folder.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade to "react-leaflet": "2.7.0".

Comment: The is the exact same answer that someone else put here.  This is not a solution to this issue at all.  To quote literally from @kboul, "Downgrading to a previous version is not a solution to the specific issue specially for those who have used the library for big projects and there are breaking changes between the two versions(2.x and 3.x). What you would do then? Rewrite all the code from scratch?".  The issue is both with the way that react-leaflet is compiled in its build process, as well as the way CRA handles the `??` operator.

Comment: It also would create much deeper issues, react-leaflet 3 is completely different than react-leaflet 2.

Answer (score -3):

I faced the same issue with the latest version of the leaflet: "^3.2.0", but I did overcome this problem by downgrading to version 2.7.0. Here what you should do:

- Delete the node_modules
- Delete the 'package-lock.json'
- Change the leaflet and react-leaflet versions in the "package.json" to : "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0" and "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
- run "npm install"
- The MapContainer component is not defined in the 2.7.0 version, so you should use the Map instead.
- Add some style (length) to the components to see the map.

Comment: Downgrading to a previous version is not a solution to the specific issue specially for those who have used the library for big projects and there are breaking changes between the two versions(2.x and 3.x). What you would do then? Rewrite all the code from scratch?