# L.Routing.control on react-leaflet v3 with hooks

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I only see that L.Routing.control works with under version 3, is there an equivalent version to it on v3? I'm trying to set up waypoint routing and directions between two points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom component to set up routing between two points using `leaflet-routing-machine`:

Install the library:

```
npm i leaflet-routing-machine
```

Import library's css file:

```
import "leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css";
```

Import library's js file:

```
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
```

Create the custom comp:

```
function Routing() {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [L.latLng(57.74, 11.94), L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)],
      routeWhileDragging: true
    }).addTo(map);

    return () => map.removeControl(routingControl);
  }, [map]);

  return null;
}
```

then use it as a regular react-leaflet component:

```
<MapContainer ...>
  ...
  <Routing/>
</MapContainer>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lroutingcontrol-on-react-leaflet-v3-with-hooks-vk6es?file=/src/App.js:116-149)

Comment: Hi! I don't have access to L.Routing.control, I'm using react-leaflet 3.1, would I need to downgrade ?

Comment: You need to install the library (`leaflet-routing-machine`) and import it to have access to `L.Routing.control`. It does not have to do with react-leaflet. It is a separate library. You already mentioned it on your question so I thought you were aware of that.

Comment: it took me a while, but it seems like lrm is not attaching to L so that  I can have access to Routing.control, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Take a look at the demo. It has all the necessary code you need to use to run the example. `L.Routing.control` is available if you have installed and imported the library I mentioned earlier. Is this clear?

Comment: I have solved the problem I was having in reference to this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat
I'm now able to run this same example code on my local environment. Thank you @kboul

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your issue