# Errors after installing react-leaflet

Tags: react-leaflet

Good day,

I want to try out Leaflet in React, but have not gotten far. I have installed `react-leaflet` using these steps:

```
npm install leaflet
npm install react react-dom leaflet
npm install react-leaflet
```

After that, I tried to run this in my React App (it's the [simple example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup) on the website):

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";

<MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
</MapContainer>
```

This resulted in a lot of errors:
[Errors1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlzOy.png)
[Errors2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17gIO.png)

**How do I resolve these errors?**

Comment: sounds simialr to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Comment: Thanks @kboul! That solved it