# Module parse failed: additional babel_loader

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, babel-loader, react-leaflet-v3

I have been using react-leaflet for a while now, and after a few weeks I deleted the files inside the node_modules and reinstalled them, and I did not touch the react-leaflet version at all, but when I try to run the project, it gives me an error.

---

./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
  |     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {

> ```
>   const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
> ```

|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node\_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In order to run it, the react-leaflet library must be downgraded.**
These are the steps:

1. remove react-leaflet: `npm uninstall react-leaflet`
2. update your react-scripts version to 3.3.0 or higher: `npm install --save react-scripts@latest`
3. remove node_module directory (optional)
4. clean cache:
   `npm cache clean --force`
5. Install the working versions:
   `npm i react-leaflet@3.1.0 @react-leaflet/core@1.0.2`

**You can now run the client doing npm start.**