# How to create a map by using react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How do I create a map using leaflet as I was doing it is showing the following.

```
./src/Map.js
Attempted import error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap').
```

Here Is My Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Map.css';
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';


function Map() {
    return (
        <div className="map">
           <LeafletMap>
             <TileLayer 
             url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
             attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
             />
           </LeafletMap>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

Comment: The error message is clear to me: `'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.` you are trying to import something that is not present in the imported module. Read the documentation, probably it is imported from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

`react-leaflet` exports a `MapContainer` component. So, change your import and slightly your code.

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

...
      return (
        <div className="map">
           <MapContainer>
             <TileLayer 
             url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
             attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
             />
           </MapContainer>
        </div>
...
```

Also, read the setup documentation at https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup/ where you'll find some useful troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I tried then it shows me another error now

Comment: [“Failed to compile : ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Comment: this new error is unrelated to the posted question; accept this answer and and post a new question.