# react-leaflet babel loade errorr: ./node_modules/react-leaflet/esm/Pane.js 25:37 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:37)

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

./node_modules/react-leaflet/esm/Pane.js 25:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:37)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |   }
  |

> const parentPaneName = props.pane ?? context.pane;
> |   const parentPane = parentPaneName ? context.map.getPane(parentPaneName) : undefined;
> |   const element = context.map.createPane(name, parentPane); to handle the result of these loaders.

i'm currently getting this error when i run react-leaflet v3.2.1. i'm currently using react v1.0.0. and react-scripts v4.0.3. Please how can i fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node\_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this steps:
1-https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-694191642 
2-https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/877#issuecomment-842167629
Then it fixed!