# unload react-Leaflet - I have problem to load Laeflet component

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, babeljs, react-leaflet

all dependencies are installed and using supported versions.
and also a right component import and use right (copy & paste from documentation)
---> when I run from my project this error happen

---

Failed to compile
./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)
File was processed with these loaders:

```
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
 |    useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
 |        if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current)
             {const options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
              |element.instance.setStyle(options);
              |optionsRef.current = options;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node\_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Comment: I read whole answer do all - but it doesn't work.