# How to correctly setup react-leaflet maps in ReactJs 18 + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, create-react-app, react-leaflet

Recently i am working on reactjs+typescript project in which i would like to add maps functionality using react-leaflet plugin, i correctly followed the documentation that can be found in https://react-leaflet.js.org but the problem is that after setting up everything the app isn't able to run, the error presented is as follows below:

> ./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib/path.js 10:39
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:39)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> |   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
> |     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {
> var options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
> |       element.instance.setStyle(options);
> |       optionsRef.current = options;

One of the recommendation i followed in order to fix the problem was to change the browserslist in the **package.json** from:

```
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

To:

```
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
```

And then delete the cache folder in node modules and restart the app, but it didn't fix the problem.

I don't know why it's not working in react 18, downgrading the react-leaflet version is not an option because as the documentation says react 18 only works with react leaflet 4 which is the latest version.

any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error "Failed to compile : ./node\_modules/@react-leaflet/core/esm/path.js 10:41 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:41)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552020/how-to-fix-error-failed-to-compile-node-modules-react-leaflet-core-esm-pat)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, i had already seen this thread, a way i found to fix this issue was to use [VITE](https://vitejs.dev) dev tool, i think is an issue with create-react-app.